# Why is doInBackground returing null in my android REST call?

Tags: android, rest, android-asynctask

In AVD, I tested the webservice `http://10.0.2.2:8080/details` and it worked fine. But in my android application, `getForObject` method returns a `null` in `doInBackground`. I have no I idea of what's wrong here. Please help me guys. Below are my codes :

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    //Added by me
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
//****** Mes dependencies for Android RestTemplate and Spring interaction
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
//*****END
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**My data class**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Moyennes {
    private String id,name,age;

    /*Getters and setters*/

    //Constructor

    public Students(){

    }  

}
```

** My activity class **

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        new HttpRequestTask().execute();
    }

    private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Students> {

        @Override
        protected Students doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // To allow Debugging 
            if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected())
                android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

            try {
                final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/details";
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                Students students = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Students.class);
                return students ;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
                Message.message(context,e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Students student) {
        String id = student.getId();
        String name = student.getName();
        String age = student.getAge();
        // some other work
    }
}
```

Comment: You must `Log` the caught exception to know why.

Comment: @Sufian ok..my computer is running slow (thanks AVD)...be right back with a possible `Log`... Actually which `Log` are you talking about ? Because for now, no exception is caught. `doInBackgroung` returns fine but with `students = null` although in chrome (of AVD) the webservice does not return empty stuff.... It's as if `getForObject` was failing because I did something wrong somewhere...

Comment: It's throwing exception in Try catch block and you are not logging it

Comment: @prathamkesarkar Maybe I don't know how to log....Anyways in `Logcat`, there is absolutely nothing. I put a breakpoint in `onPostExecute`. When the app stops there, the variable `student` is `null`. Sme thing when I put the breakpoint on the `return` in the `try`. Note that whether in AVD or on my local machine, browsers are able to call the webservice withtout any trouble

Comment: @Sufian Please see my comment above

Comment: Could you update your question with the LogCat?

Comment: In your catch block, write following line, then run your code and update your question with LogCat: `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: @Sufian no need. I found something (maybe it was the reason). My REST webservice was returning a `List<Student>` (in JSON) and I was using in `doInBackground` the following `Students students = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Students.class);` So returning a `List<Object>` in `Object` was not working (still don't know why it'd say `null`).. Anyways I changed that and it worked fine after that. Thank you mate

Comment: @YvetteColomb haha you are too kind. I am not mad Yevette I just did not understand the votes.  For that question I solved it. It was related to the fact that the return type of the webservice (to a JSON) could not be understood by the application. App was expecting something it could convert to an `<Object>` but was receiving a `List<Object>` from `getForObject`. When I corrected that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering here : `Students` class is a class for 1 student ; not a List of students.

The problem was related to the fact that the return type of the webservice (though a JSON) could not be understood by the application. App was expecting something it could convert to an  but was receiving a List from getForObject.

To solve it, below are the changes made to `doInBackground` :

```
@Override
protected Students[] doInBackground(Integer... params) {

    if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected()) // To allow Debugging => using breaking points below in doInBackground
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

        try {
            publishProgress(count);
            final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/details";

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

            ResponseEntity<Students[]> res = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Students[].class);
            Students[] m = res.getBody();

            return m;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error : ", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    return null;
}
```